# Swift, nested dictionary with different type

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I need to have my data like this, so I can return it as `NSDictionary`?, please refer to my code below

```
{
    "aaa": "a1",  //value: String type
    "bbb": "b1",
    "ccc": "c1",
    "ddd": "d1",  
    "dict2": {
        "zzz": "z2",  //String type, but sometimes will be nil
        "ttt": "t2",
        "kkk": null,
        "sss": null,
    }
}
```

code:

```
let dict2Info = ["zzz":z1, "ttt":t1, "ccc":c1, "kkk":null, "sss":null]

    var dict1 = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        dict["aaa"] = a1
        dict["bbb"] = b1
        dict["ccc"] = c1
        dict["dict2"] = dict2Info as? AnyObject
println("\(dict1)")

return dict1   //return parameter type is "NSDictionary?"

// result:  [aaa: a1, bbb: b1, ccc: c1]
```

problem:

1. `dict2` is missing (I have checked the `key` in dictionary, `dict2` is not exist)
2. need to return `NSDictionary`?

Please help me!

Comment: @senHeLee try to put : instead of =.

Answer (score 3):

```
var outerDic = [String:Any]()
var innerDic = [String:String?]()

outerDic["aaa"] = "a1"
outerDic["bbb"] = "b1"
outerDic["ccc"] = "c1"
outerDic["ddd"] = "d1"

innerDic["zzz"] = "z2"
innerDic["ttt"] = "t2"
innerDic["kkk"] = nil
innerDic["sss"] = nil

outerDic["dict2"] = innerDic

println(outerDic)
```

Comment: Hi @gutenmorgenuhu, thank you very much, is there any possible way to turn outerDict from [String: Any]  to NSDictionary?

Comment: By the way, I modify a little bit like this => 
let innerDic = ["zzz":z2, "ttt":t2, "kkk":nil, "sss":nil]
var outerDict:[String:Any] = ["aaa": a1!, "bbb": b1, "ccc" : c1, "ddd": d1, "inner":innerDic]

Comment: Swift should be able to accept the Dictionary in every circumstance a NSDictionary is requested.

Comment: let dict = outerDict as? NSDictionary
Error: Cast from '[String : Any]' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails
print(dict) //I get nil
the cast will fail, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: outerDict should be able to used in any context which accepts an NSDictionary

Answer (score 1):

The dict2 isnt missing, you just havent declared it like a dictionary, but as `AnyObject`.

Your mistake is at casting the `dict["dict2"] as? AnyObject`, but tje `"dict2"` is actually a Dictionary. Do it like this:

```
dict["dict2"] = dict2Info as? NSDictionary?
```

Note that the value `dict2` in the json is type of `NSDictionary?` so you need to cast it like this too.

Also dont forget to cast it as **optional** (because of nils).